# How can I join three tables in SQL?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I'm faced with following problem, I'm not sure how to tackle it. I have a rough idea, but I'm not sure how I would execute it.

Here is the issue

Table **A exist** in the following format:

```
Name    | Name_Att| Name2 | Name_Att2 
--------+---------+-------+-------
ryan    |  red    | xyz   |  green
```

Likewise **Table B** exist in this format:

```
Name    | Name_id |  
--------+---------+
ryan    | 123     |
xyz     | 129     |
```

Likewise **Table C** exist in this format:

```
Name_Att| C_id    | Name_id  
--------+---------+---------
red     | 4591    | 123
green   | 4592    | 123
blue    | 4593    | 123
green   | 4594    | 129
blue    | 4595    | 129
```

**So I'm trying to create the following table:**

```
Name_id |  C_id   |Name_id2 | C_id2  
--------+---------+---------+----------
123     | 4591    | 129     | 4594
```

Is there any way I should go about this? I was thinking about writing code to do this. I'm sure there is SQL way to accomplish this. However I'm not sure.

Comment: Are all tables within the same RDBMS? Which one?

Comment: *So I'm trying to create the following table*...and where is your trial, albeit trial and error? SO is not a code-writing or tutorial service. Please attempt an earnest effort.

Comment: Appears you just need to join from A to B, from A&B to C twice.  once for Name_ID and once form NameID2 alias the tables since your joining twice.

Answer (score 2):

Try to include the following joins in your solution:

```
FROM (TableA INNER JOIN TableB ON TableA.Name = TableB.Name) 
INNER JOIN TableC ON (TableA.Name_Att = TableC.Name_Att) AND
    (TableB.Name_id = TableC.Name_id)
```

You can do the same thing to get `Name_Id2` and `C_id2`; make sure to alias your table names correctly.

Comment: That will not work in Access, Access needs parenthesis in its JOIN statements. The easiest way to do it is to use the query UI to join the tables and then copy/paste the SQL it generates and clean it up (but do not remove the parenthesis from the FROM section).